# Menu fixed on top after scrolling - Good or Bad?

Tags: menu, scrolling, fixed-header

I was wondering if it is a good thing to have a fixed menu on top of the screen after the user scrolls, this seems to be a growing tendency and I'm not sure what to think about it.

Example:

- http://circles.arenaofthemes.com/

Your opinion is different if the [layout is boxed](http://circles.arenaofthemes.com/?switch_layout=b960)?

Comment: Hi @Lucas.  Welcome to the UX Stack Exchange!  I think your question already has an answer:  "[Fixed-position header and menu on a web page -- is that okay?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7287/fixed-position-header-and-menu-on-a-web-page-is-that-okay)"

Comment: The 'reflow the header and make it sticky as you scroll' was 'cool' the first 20 times I saw it. But it's getting a bit tired. I find it incredibly distracting that as I scroll, stuff is animating and rearranging elsewhere on the screen. If you don't think the content on your site is important, by all means, distract people from reading it. :D